# Google Apps Script - Which one is sending e-mail?

Tags: google-apps-script

So, this is odd...

I have a Google Apps script set to trigger every night around midnight to send me an email.  I changed the script to alter the body of the email ... but now I get two e-mails every night - one with the "original" body and one reflecting the changes.

There is only a single timed trigger.
There is only one call to send the e-mail.

Is there any way to backtrace what's causing the "old" one to fire, given that  I can't find any code anywhere that would be doing it?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Is there only one trigger in "Edit > All you triggers"?

Comment: Yes, but good thought.